# Error when connection to mongodb version 6

Tags: mongodb, scala, play-reactivemongo

I upgraded play-reactivemongo driver form version 0.16.2-play27 to version 1.1.0-play27-RC6
After fixing the code issues, I get an "Fails to send a isMaster request" error when trying to run the app against MongoDB ver 6 server with the same connection string as earlier when using MongoDB server ver 4.
Did anyone counter something like this issue? Thanks

Environment: Play 2.7.0
Scala 2.11.12
Mongo Server 6.0.3
SBT 0.13.18

```
Connection string: "mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@general.foba0.mongodb.net/envoy4?ssl=true&authenticationDatabase=admin&authenticationMechanism=scram-sha1&readPreference=primaryPreferred&rm.nbChannelsPerNode=25&rm.failover=remote&rm.tcpNoDelay=true&rm.keepAlive=true&heartbeatFrequencyMS=5000"
```

```
--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] p.c.s.AkkaHttpServer - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

Server started, use Cmd+P to stop

2022-12-13 09:57:14,186 - [warn] application - Logger configuration in conf files is deprecated and has no effect. Use a logback configuration file instead.
2022-12-13 09:57:14,569 - [info] r.a.MongoConnection - Connection option 'replicaSet' is ignored: determined from servers response
2022-12-13 09:57:14,574 - [info] r.a.MongoConnection - Connection option 'authenticationDatabase' is deprecated in favor of 'authSource'
2022-12-13 09:57:16,508 - [warn] application - application.conf @ file:/Users/Yuri/devroot/core/target/scala-2.11/classes/application.conf: 8: play.crypto.secret is deprecated, use play.http.secret.key instead
2022-12-13 09:57:16,543 - [warn] application - application.langs is deprecated, use play.i18n.langs instead
2022-12-13 09:57:16,786 - [info] e.d.CheckoutLogPersister - ensuring indexes List(Index(List((createDate,desc)),None,false,false,None,false,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,BSONDocument(<non-empty>)), Index(List((key,asc)),None,false,false,None,false,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,BSONDocument(<empty>))) exist for collection checkoutSessionLog by object envoy.data.CheckoutLogPersister@7a4db7ed
2022-12-13 09:57:16,850 - [info] r.api.Driver - [Supervisor-1] Creating connection: envoy4
2022-12-13 09:57:16,887 - [info] r.c.a.MongoDBSystem - [Supervisor-1/envoy4] Starting the MongoDBSystem
2022-12-13 09:57:16,910 - [info] r.c.netty.Pack - Instantiated reactivemongo.core.netty.Pack
2022-12-13 09:57:17,271 - [info] e.d.QuoteLogPersister - ensuring indexes List(Index(List((createDate,desc)),None,false,false,None,false,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,BSONDocument(<non-empty>)), Index(List((key,asc)),None,false,false,None,false,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,BSONDocument(<empty>))) exist for collection quoteLog by object envoy.data.QuoteLogPersister@24ba159e
2022-12-13 09:57:17,280 - [info] e.d.OrderLogPersister - ensuring indexes List(Index(List((createDate,desc)),None,false,false,None,false,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,BSONDocument(<non-empty>)), Index(List((key,asc)),None,false,false,None,false,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,BSONDocument(<empty>))) exist for collection orderLog by object envoy.data.OrderLogPersister@13ba1fb0
2022-12-13 09:57:17,284 - [info] e.d.AlipayLogPersister - ensuring indexes List(Index(List((createDate,desc)),None,false,false,None,false,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,BSONDocument(<non-empty>)), Index(List((key,asc)),None,false,false,None,false,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,BSONDocument(<empty>))) exist for collection alipayLog by object envoy.data.AlipayLogPersister@572a2863
2022-12-13 09:57:17,285 - [info] e.d.AlipayPersister - ensuring indexes List(Index(List((createDate,desc)),None,false,false,None,false,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,BSONDocument(<non-empty>)), Index(List((key,asc)),None,false,false,None,false,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,BSONDocument(<empty>))) exist for collection alipay by object envoy.data.AlipayPersister@20a0e45d
2022-12-13 09:57:17,286 - [info] e.d.AlipayAsyncPersister - ensuring indexes List(Index(List((createDate,desc)),None,false,false,None,false,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,BSONDocument(<non-empty>)), Index(List((key,asc)),None,false,false,None,false,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,BSONDocument(<empty>))) exist for collection alipayAsync by object envoy.data.AlipayAsyncPersister@6b12437a
2022-12-13 09:57:17,288 - [info] e.d.AlipayStatusPersister - ensuring indexes List(Index(List((createDate,desc)),None,false,false,None,false,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,BSONDocument(<non-empty>)), Index(List((key,asc)),None,false,false,None,false,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,BSONDocument(<empty>))) exist for collection alipayStatus by object envoy.data.AlipayStatusPersister@2009a18
2022-12-13 09:57:17,301 - [info] e.d.AltPayLogPersister - ensuring indexes List(Index(List((createDate,desc)),None,false,false,None,false,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,BSONDocument(<non-empty>)), Index(List((key,asc)),None,false,false,None,false,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,BSONDocument(<empty>))) exist for collection altPayLog by object envoy.data.AltPayLogPersister@41f92064
2022-12-13 09:57:17,303 - [info] e.d.ViewStatePersister - ensuring indexes List(Index(List((createDate,desc)),None,false,false,None,false,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,BSONDocument(<non-empty>)), Index(List((key,asc)),None,false,false,None,false,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,BSONDocument(<empty>)), Index(List((mapping,asc)),None,false,false,None,false,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,BSONDocument(<empty>))) exist for collection viewState by object envoy.data.ViewStatePersister@389159bd
2022-12-13 09:57:17,304 - [info] e.d.ViewStatePersister - ensuring indexes List(Index(List((createDate,desc)),None,false,false,None,false,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,BSONDocument(<non-empty>)), Index(List((key,asc)),None,false,false,None,false,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,BSONDocument(<empty>)), Index(List((mapping,asc)),None,false,false,None,false,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,BSONDocument(<empty>))) exist for collection viewState by object envoy.data.ViewStatePersister@1a797a7d
2022-12-13 09:57:17,497 - [info] play.api.Play - Application started (Dev)
2022-12-13 09:57:17,500 - [warn] play.api.Play - 
You are using the deprecated global state to set and access the current running application. If you
need an instance of Application, set play.allowGlobalApplication = false and use Dependency Injection instead.
        
2022-12-13 09:57:17,754 - [trace] e.f.f.RequestLoggingFilter - headers=Map(Host -> localhost:9000, Accept -> text/css,*/*;q=0.1, Cookie -> Idea-4047ded2=367b6c6c-5394-4485-8041-f02bba186f6e, Referer -> http://localhost:9000/, sec-ch-ua -> "Not?A_Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="108", "Google Chrome";v="108", Connection -> keep-alive, User-Agent -> Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36, If-None-Match -> "4ae3bb8b28e944372535986873b374cf65caad13", Remote-Address -> 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:50853, Sec-Fetch-Dest -> style, Sec-Fetch-Mode -> no-cors, Sec-Fetch-Site -> same-origin, Timeout-Access -> <function1>, Accept-Encoding -> gzip, deflate, br, Accept-Language -> en-US,en;q=0.9,ru-RU;q=0.8,ru;q=0.7,he-IL;q=0.6,he;q=0.5, Raw-Request-URI -> /assets/stylesheets/main.css, sec-ch-ua-mobile -> ?0, Tls-Session-Info -> [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL], If-Modified-Since -> Tue, 08 Dec 2020 08:05:34 GMT, sec-ch-ua-platform -> "macOS"), path=/assets/stylesheets/main.css, method=GET
2022-12-13 09:57:17,761 - [trace] e.f.f.RequestLoggingFilter - headers=Map(Host -> localhost:9000, Accept -> */*, Cookie -> Idea-4047ded2=367b6c6c-5394-4485-8041-f02bba186f6e, Referer -> http://localhost:9000/, sec-ch-ua -> "Not?A_Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="108", "Google Chrome";v="108", Connection -> keep-alive, User-Agent -> Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36, Remote-Address -> 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:50855, Sec-Fetch-Dest -> script, Sec-Fetch-Mode -> no-cors, Sec-Fetch-Site -> same-origin, Timeout-Access -> <function1>, Accept-Encoding -> gzip, deflate, br, Accept-Language -> en-US,en;q=0.9,ru-RU;q=0.8,ru;q=0.7,he-IL;q=0.6,he;q=0.5, Raw-Request-URI -> /assets/javascripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js, sec-ch-ua-mobile -> ?0, Tls-Session-Info -> [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL], sec-ch-ua-platform -> "macOS"), path=/assets/javascripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js, method=GET
2022-12-13 09:57:18,060 - [trace] e.f.f.RequestLoggingFilter - headers=Map(Host -> localhost:9000, Accept -> image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,image/svg+xml,image/*,*/*;q=0.8, Cookie -> Idea-4047ded2=367b6c6c-5394-4485-8041-f02bba186f6e, Referer -> http://localhost:9000/, sec-ch-ua -> "Not?A_Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="108", "Google Chrome";v="108", Connection -> keep-alive, User-Agent -> Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36, If-None-Match -> "4e502da8bdd7ae9dbcba1d69b8e84a24c8bb1218", Remote-Address -> 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:50855, Sec-Fetch-Dest -> image, Sec-Fetch-Mode -> no-cors, Sec-Fetch-Site -> same-origin, Timeout-Access -> <function1>, Accept-Encoding -> gzip, deflate, br, Accept-Language -> en-US,en;q=0.9,ru-RU;q=0.8,ru;q=0.7,he-IL;q=0.6,he;q=0.5, Raw-Request-URI -> /assets/images/favicon.png, sec-ch-ua-mobile -> ?0, Tls-Session-Info -> [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL], If-Modified-Since -> Tue, 08 Dec 2020 08:05:34 GMT, sec-ch-ua-platform -> "macOS"), path=/assets/images/favicon.png, method=GET
2022-12-13 09:57:20,034 - [info] e.d.AlipayStatusPersister - method=ensureIndexes, description='succcesfully ensured indexes on alipayStatus
2022-12-13 09:57:20,035 - [info] e.d.AlipayAsyncPersister - method=ensureIndexes, description='succcesfully ensured indexes on alipayAsync
2022-12-13 09:57:20,035 - [info] e.d.AltPayLogPersister - method=ensureIndexes, description='succcesfully ensured indexes on altPayLog
2022-12-13 09:57:20,034 - [info] e.d.AlipayLogPersister - method=ensureIndexes, description='succcesfully ensured indexes on alipayLog
2022-12-13 09:57:20,033 - [info] e.d.ViewStatePersister - method=ensureIndexes, description='succcesfully ensured indexes on viewState
2022-12-13 09:57:20,050 - [info] e.d.OrderLogPersister - method=ensureIndexes, description='succcesfully ensured indexes on orderLog
2022-12-13 09:57:20,052 - [info] e.d.AlipayPersister - method=ensureIndexes, description='succcesfully ensured indexes on alipay
2022-12-13 09:57:20,052 - [info] e.d.ViewStatePersister - method=ensureIndexes, description='succcesfully ensured indexes on viewState
2022-12-13 09:57:20,053 - [info] e.d.CheckoutLogPersister - method=ensureIndexes, description='succcesfully ensured indexes on checkoutSessionLog
2022-12-13 09:57:20,063 - [info] e.d.QuoteLogPersister - method=ensureIndexes, description='succcesfully ensured indexes on quoteLog
2022-12-13 09:57:52,371 - [error] r.c.a.MongoDBSystem - [Supervisor-1/envoy4] Fails to send a isMaster request to cbr-atlas-dev-general-shard-00-00.foba0.mongodb.net:27017 (channel #508fd418)
reactivemongo.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslClosedEngineException: SSLEngine closed already
    at reactivemongo.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrap(SslHandler.java:860)
    at reactivemongo.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrapAndFlush(SslHandler.java:799)
    at reactivemongo.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.flush(SslHandler.java:780)
    at reactivemongo.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:750)
    at reactivemongo.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:742)
2022-12-13 09:57:52,371 - [error] r.c.a.MongoDBSystem - [Supervisor-1/envoy4] Fails to send a isMaster request to cbr-atlas-dev-general-shard-00-01.foba0.mongodb.net:27017 (channel #392ce790)
reactivemongo.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslClosedEngineException: SSLEngine closed already
    at reactivemongo.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrap(SslHandler.java:860)
    at reactivemongo.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrapAndFlush(SslHandler.java:799)
    at reactivemongo.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.flush(SslHandler.java:780)
    at reactivemongo.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:750)
    at reactivemongo.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:742)
2022-12-13 09:57:52,371 - [error] r.c.a.MongoDBSystem - [Supervisor-1/envoy4] Fails to send a isMaster request to cbr-atlas-dev-general-shard-00-02.foba0.mongodb.net:27017 (channel #f701a0f0)
reactivemongo.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslClosedEngineException: SSLEngine closed already
    at reactivemongo.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrap(SslHandler.java:860)
    at reactivemongo.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrapAndFlush(SslHandler.java:799)
    at reactivemongo.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.flush(SslHandler.java:780)
    at reactivemongo.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:750)
    at reactivemongo.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:742)
2022-12-13 09:57:52,375 - [warn] r.c.p.MongoHandler - [Supervisor-1/envoy4] Channel is closed under 12838583ns: cbr-atlas-dev-general-shard-00-01.foba0.mongodb.net/192.168.153.113:27017; Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. (channel [id: 0x392ce790, L:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:50857 ! R:cbr-atlas-dev-general-shard-00-01.foba0.mongodb.net/192.168.153.113:27017])
2022-12-13 09:57:52,375 - [warn] r.c.p.MongoHandler - [Supervisor-1/envoy4] Channel is closed under 12599708ns: cbr-atlas-dev-general-shard-00-00.foba0.mongodb.net/192.168.153.186:27017; Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. (channel [id: 0x508fd418, L:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:50859 ! R:cbr-atlas-dev-general-shard-00-00.foba0.mongodb.net/192.168.153.186:27017])
2022-12-13 09:57:52,376 - [warn] r.c.p.MongoHandler - [Supervisor-1/envoy4] Channel is closed under 12856208ns: cbr-atlas-dev-general-shard-00-02.foba0.mongodb.net/192.168.153.43:27017; Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. (channel [id: 0xf701a0f0, L:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:50860 ! R:cbr-atlas-dev-general-shard-00-02.foba0.mongodb.net/192.168.153.43:27017])
2022-12-13 09:57:52,390 - [warn] r.c.a.MongoDBSystem - [Supervisor-1/envoy4] The entire node set is unreachable, is there a network problem?
```

Comment: RC6 means Release Candidate ...

Comment: Thanks, but I mentioned that I updated the play-reactive mongo driver to the newer version.

Comment: @cchantep would you suggest waiting for the final version?

Comment: I want to add that using same connection string with the command line mongo tool works fine. So it seems like an issue with the driver.

Comment: Is your MongoDB a standalone or a replica set?